# Input texts go back to default value after click

Tags: javascript, html

The form below is working as I want except for one thing. When I click the 'Add' link I the texts of all the textboxes go back to its default value like seen in the images. How can I fix it? Thanks.

before click:

[image: first image]

after click on 'Add':

[image: second image]

Code:

```
function addSection() {
    var str = '<div>' + 
                '<input type="text" name="composer" value="Compositor" />' + 
                '<input type="text" name="peca" value="Peca" size="40" />' + 
                '<input type="button" value="x" style="width: 26px" onclick="delSection(this)" /><br />' + 
            '</div>';

    document.getElementById("programa").innerHTML += str;
}

function delSection(field) {
    field.parentNode.outerHTML = "";
}

window.onload = addSection;

</script>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Programa</legend>
    <div id="programa">
    </div>
    <a href="#" onclick="addSection()" >Add</a><br />
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Inscrever Aluno" name="submit" />
```

Comment: Check out my answer. I think i got your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overcome this, using `appendChild()`

JS

```
function newSet() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");   

    var composer = document.createElement("input");
    composer.type="text";
    composer.value = "Compositer";

    var peca = document.createElement("input");
    peca.type = "text";
    peca.value = "Peca";

    var button = document.createElement("input");
    button.type = "submit"

    div.appendChild(composer);
    div.appendChild(peca);
    div.appendChild(button);

    return div
}

function addSection() {    
    document.getElementById("programa").appendChild(newSet());
}
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/sK8MR/)

Comment: even clearer and cleaner than the previous accepted answer. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct JS to insert new elements:

```
function addSection() {
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var str =   '<input type="text" name="composer" value="Compositor" />' + 
                '<input type="text" name="peca" value="Peca" size="40" />' + 
                '<input type="button" value="x" style="width: 26px" onclick="delSection(this)" /><br />';
    newDiv.innerHTML = str;
    document.getElementById("programa").appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

You need to find a solution for naming (or identification) of the elements so you can remove them with `delSelection(field)`

Comment: Personally, I'd avoid `innerHTML` altogether, but this solves the problem. Pulling a serialisation of the HTML out gives you value attributes with the default value and not the current value, so when you (after appending the new string) overwrite the old `innerHTML` value, you trash the data. This answer shows how to avoid overwriting the old `innerHTML` value.

Comment: @Quentin, Check out my answer, and tell If it is correct performance wise on this

Comment: @Starx I agree it is more readable and clean code. My solution came as "shortcut" to overcome the problem.

Answer (score 0):

create a name like `name="composer[]"` and `name="peca[]"`

if you don't understand how to implement the above code then go to

http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/21/how-to-dynamically-add-form-elements-via-javascript/

Comment: That would solve the problem if the question said "Only the first item is showing up in the data I'm submitting to PHP" (because PHP has some unfortunately limitations when handling multiple form inputs with the same name) … but that isn't what the question says.